# HttpContex null on wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, httpcontext, appserver

i have 2 servers  web server and the app server 
on the app server i have WCF running .
in any function on the wcf i"m trying to get the current user 
with System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User but i"m getting null
there is a way to get the user without move it with paramter to the any functions ?

Comment: What is your wcf configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity`.

Comment: ServiceSecurityContext.Current is null

Comment: Ok working http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/identity-securitycallcontext-in-wcf/ thanks

Answer (score 2):

WCF tries to distance itself from ASP.NET, because it can run in any number of hosts - not just ASP.NET. This also allows it to cut out large chunks of the ASP.NET pipe, improving throughput. You can force it to use ASP.NET mode by adding:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

to the configuration, but frankly you're better off (IMO) using the thread principal instead. WCF has full support for the principal model.